# Google PHP API too many files

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a plugin for WordPress using the Google Analytics Reporting API v4 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php

We need to load the Google API PHP Client Library
`require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

I have downloaded the latest release of Google API https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases but the vendor folder contains more than 7000 files!

My question is if I am doing something wrong here or I am missing something? Inside the vendor folder I can see all the Google services. How I can use the Google API with less files in a WordPress plugin? I will appreciate any help to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Google/Service directory contains all the code needed to access every Google Discovery services API.   You don't technically need all of the files.  You can safely delete everything under Google/Service that you don't need.

Dont delete files from any of the other directories.  Just remove the unneeded APIs.

Comment: @DalmTo thank you for your answer I will try it. Are there any other folders I can remove from "vendor" folder? Also there are a lot of "tests" folders, Is safe to delete them?

Comment: I have only ever removed from the Google/Services folder I have always left everything else becouse i was never sure what was used and what wasnt.   The only thing else i can say is try but if it doesnt work put it back.