# Google API PHP CLIENT > 10000 files, can't upload to APP ENGINE service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-php-client

i've download the google api php client from 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases

I need to push the project + this code on an app engine versione, problem is that i got an error when gcloud: *ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.*

I've ignored all files from project, but only the google api php client directory has **10.646** files.

I can't undestand which file are required for me(i need just API to switch on/off a VM on compute engine)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214056/google-php-api-too-many-files <--- Does not resolve my question, had already seen it. Google/Service is not enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may delete folders from services you don't intend to use in the following top folder :

```
google-api-php-client-2.4.0\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service
```

You should have no more than some hundred of files after that.